# Search Box Hides Links

Tags: zurb-foundation, navbar

I'm wondering if this is a Foundation bug, or if I've missed something in my code. My nav bar is structured as follows:

```
<div class="sticky noprint">
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar role="navigation">

  <ul class="title-area">
    <!-- This li needs to be here for for some strange reason to make the mobile menu work -->
    <li class="name">
        <!-- <h1><a href="">Home</a></h1> -->
    </li>
    <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon">
        <a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">

    <!-- Left Nav Section -->
    <ul class="left">

      <!-- Class Dropdown -->
      <!-- <li><img src="background180.png" alt="background120" width="225" height="60"></li> -->
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="classes.php">Courses</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="classes.php">All Classes</a></li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                        <a href="#">Course Admin</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="searchcourse.php">Search for a Course</a></li>
                            <li><a href="searchcourse.php">Edit a Course</a></li>
                            <li><a href="editcourse.php">Add a Course</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- Class Dropdown Ends -->

       <!-- Learner Dropdown -->
       <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="searchstu.php">Learner</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="searchstu.php">Search for a Learner</a></li>
          <li><a href="editstudent.php">Add a Learner</a></li> <li><a href="searchstu.php">Edit a Learner</a></li>
                    <li><a href="selectstu.php?all=true">List All Active Learners</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- Learner Dropdown Ends -->

      <!-- Grades Dropdown -->
       <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Grades</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#">View and Enter Grades</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="gradesbycourse.php">All Courses</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Grade Templates</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="addgradetemplate.php">Create Template</a></li>
                        <li><a href="editgradetemplate.php">Active Templates</a></li>
                        <li><a href="editgradetemplate.php?all=true">All Templates</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
      <!-- Grades Dropdown Ends -->

      <!-- Employee Dropdown -->
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="searchemp.php">Employee</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">

         <li><a href="editemp.php">Add an Employee</a></li>
         <li><a href="searchemp.php">Edit an Employee</a></li>
         <li><a href="searchemp.php">Search for an Employee</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>
      <!-- Employee Dropdown Ends -->

      <!-- Reports Dropdown -->
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Reports</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="has-dropdown">
            <a href="#">Program</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="newstus.php">New Registrations</a></li>
                            <li><a href="email.php?program=1">Email All Active Students</a></li>
                            <!-- <li><a href="email.php?program=1">Email All Active Students Using Your Default Client</a></li> -->
                            <li><a href="reports.php">Weekly Course Report (Your Courses)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="reportsactive.php">Weekly Course Report (Active Courses)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="reportsinactive.php">Weekly Class Report (Inactive Courses)</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gradestoenter.php">Grades</a></li>
                            <li><a href="gradestoenterold.php">Grades (Old System)</a></li>
                            <!-- <li><a href="reportprogram.php">Program Totals</a></li> -->
                            <!-- <li><a href="ministryaction.php">IMS Action</a></li> -->
                            <!-- <li><a href="exitneedsaction.php">Exited Needs Action</a></li> -->
                </ul>
            </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Reporting</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="newregcsv.php">New Reg CSV for</a></li>
                            <li><a href="newregcsv.php">New Reg CSV for</a></li>
                            <li><a href="activenoeois.php">Active - No</a></li>
                            <li><a href="banneraction.php">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="3monthfu.php">Exit 3-Month Follow-up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="6monthfu.php">Exit 6-Month Follow-up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="12monthfu.php">Exit 12-Month Follow-up</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#">Counsellor</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="notattending.php">100 Day No Attendance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="activenoclasses.php">Active - No Classes</a></li>
                            <!-- <li><a href="3monthpause.php">Pause 3-Month Follow-up</a></li> -->
                            <!-- <li><a href="allonpause.php">All Paused Students</a></li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown">
                    <a href="#">DUP</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="activenoeoisd.php">Active - No</a></li>
                            <li><a href="banneractiond.php">Banner Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="3monthfud.php">Exit 3-Month Follow-up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="6monthfud.php">Exit 6-Month Follow-up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="12monthfud.php">Exit 12-Month Follow-up</a></li>
                            <li><a href="notattendingd.php">100 Day No Attendance</a></li>
                            <li><a href="activenoclassesd.php">Active - No Classes</a></li>
                            <!-- <li><a href="3monthpaused.php">Pause 3-Month Follow-up</a></li> -->
                            <!-- <li><a href="allonpaused.php">All Paused Students</a></li> -->
                            <!-- <li><a href="exitneedsactiond.php">Exited Needs Action</a></li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Account</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
              <!-- <li class="active"><a href="#">Right Button Active</a></li> -->
              <li><a href="mailto:">Request Access</a></li>
            <li><a href="mailto:">Report Bugs</a></li>

                <li><a href="login.php">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="editemp.php?enum=">Edit Your Account</a></li>
                    <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
      <!-- Reports Dropdown Ends -->

    </ul>
    <!-- Left Nav Ends -->

    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
        <li class="has-form">
        <form name="form" action="select.php" method="get">
            <div class="row collapse">
                <div class="large-8 small-9 columns">
                    <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="height: 29px" placeholder="">
                </div>
                <div class="large-4 small-3 columns">
                  <input type="submit" class="button expand" value="Search">
                </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- End Right Nav Section -->

  </section>
</nav>
</div>
```

So what I'm wondering is: Desktop works perfectly. When I shrink to mobile screen size, perform a search, the search bar now takes over the entire menu and won't show the hamburger menu as it's supposed to. Can anyone suggest a fix? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry, had to switch computers to copy and paste code. Question is now complete.

Comment: Your code snippet is much to large and complex, and it shouldn't include PHP. Please create a simplified, minimal demo *with your CSS*. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: No problem, I will fix it up.

Comment: Ok, it's been condensed. I know it's still long, but I'm hesitant to remove any more code in case I remove the problem itself. Thanks in advance to anyone who can find out why the search bar is taking over the entire menu in mobile view.